# Domain configuration with HTTP_REFERER and HTTP_HOST

Tags: php, dns

We have a Magento website which uses 3 domain names to serve different stores, for example:

1. store.ca serves Canadian (CA) store
2. store.com.au serves Australain (AU) store
3. store.com serves American (US) store.

We detect the domain name in `index.php` of the application using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` which works very well for `store.ca` and `store.com.au` but does not work for `store.com`, here is what i found out.

Doing `var_dump($_SERVER)` on domain names gives me following result.

1. Domain: store.ca

   - `HTTP_HOST: store.ca`
2. Domain: store.com.au

   - `HTTP_HOST: store.com.au`
3. Domain: store.com

   - `HTTP_HOST: store.ca`
   - `HTTP_REFERER: http://store.com/`

Problem is with the `US` store, i am wondering what's wrong, why is different domain shown in `HTTP_HOST` and the correct one in `HTTP_REFERER`? is it because of domain redirection, masking or any other possibility?

I have no control over the domain name hence i am trying to figure out why, so i can get back to the client and ask him to do necessary changes.

Thanks.

Comment: That depends on how the web server is set up. Is there some internal proxy forwarding going on or so?

Comment: The server has cPanel, the only domain configuration that was done was by adding the 3 domains from "Add on domains".

Comment: I cannot see any related changes in webserver,